# Strapi v4 - images uploaded to S3 are not displayed in media gallery

Tags: strapi

I'm trying out the new Strapi v4. I installed the provider-upload-aws-s3 to upload my images to S3 and configured it. I do see my images in the S3 bucket, but I do not see them in the Media Gallery. I inspected request and I see I'm getting this error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at {my img URL}.

When trying to get the image directly in the browser with the same URL and the image is being loaded.

I believe it has something to do with this warning (quote from Strapi documentation):

> Strapi has a default Security Middleware that has a very strict contentSecurityPolicy that limits loading images and media to "'self'" only, see the example configuration on the provider page or take a look at our middleare documentation for more information.

But I'm not sure what to do with it and how to override it. So how do I make the uploaded to S3 images appear in the Media Gallery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, at this point I was really sure it's a bug and reported it at Strapi Github issues. But according to [this answer](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11906#issuecomment-993917093) I received some more configuration had to be done in `middlewares.js` file:

```js
module.exports = [
  "strapi::errors",
  {
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "your-s3-url",
          ],
          "media-src": ["'self'", "data:", "blob:"],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];
```

I changed `your-s3-url` to `*.amazonaws.com` and then everything finally worked.

Comment: I am using didgital ocean spaces and facing the same issue my images are public there how can i solve it

Comment: @sarangkkl Though I can't be 100% sure as I'm not using DO, but look at this thread on official Strapi forum: https://forum.strapi.io/t/upload-media-to-digitalocean-spaces-using-strapi-v4/16135

Comment: I had the exact same issue, worked perfectly for me, thanks for raising the issue on github